# EF Core 7: .Any() in query filter produce "could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I use pretty simple entity Request (see example below) and custom query filter ByStatuses as extension. When I use .ToArrayAsync() I got an exception "could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated"

```
public class Request
{
    public virtual RequestStatus Status { get; set; }
    public int? StatusId { get; set; }
}

public static IQueryable<Request> ByStatuses(this IQueryable<Request> query, IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
        return query.Where(o => ids.Any(oo => o.StatusId == oo));
 }

var local = await query.ToArrayAsync();
```

If I change to this

```
        return query.Where(o => o.StatusId != null && ids.Any(oo => o.StatusId == oo));
```

and use .UseRelationalNulls() for context options - this doesnt change anything.
Are "Any" and "All" operators doesnt supported in EF 7 pretty well? Or they cant be used in complex query chains? Or this is problem with null property in table row?

Error:

```
The LINQ expression 'oo => EntityShaperExpression: 
    X5.TC5.TC.Domain.Entities.Request
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False
.StatusId == (int?)oo' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: Try .Where(o => ids.Contains(o.StatusId))

Comment: +1 `Contains` is what you're looking for. `Any` on the Enumerable cannot be translated down to SQL as the set is in memory. `Contains` on the other hand is supported to produce an `IN` clause. There will be limits on the maximum # of items in the set depending on the database engine/provider.

Comment: I cannot use .Contains becouse of some permissions of app. "Any" works if I change nullable "StatusId?" to not nullable StatusId. This is a reason I guess?
But how can I set up an entity or something so that this nullable property be evaluated to server-side query with Any operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out this is a bug in EF Core 7.0 https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/31081